# How to save a stdin data in a JSON in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, stdout, stdin

I have the following problem, I want some questions to be asked in my console, and when I receive the answers I save them in a json and then use them, I am not very familiar with Nodejs, I suppose it is something simple but it does not work for me

When trying to send `customer.Token = answers [1];` what happens is that "token" no longer exists in my json. And for example if I use `customer.Token =" Hi ";` my json file changes perfectly

I need the answer that the user is giving at that moment to be sent

I've been trying all morning to make this work but I can't find a solution, if someone knows <3 it would help me a lot

here below I leave my code

```
   const customer = require('./db.json');

const fs = require("fs");

function jsonReader(filePath, cb) {
  fs.readFile(filePath, (err, fileData) => {
    if (err) {
      return cb && cb(err);
    }
    try {
      const object = JSON.parse(fileData);
      return cb && cb(null, object);
    } catch (err) {
      return cb && cb(err);
    }
  });
}

jsonReader("./db.json", (err, customer) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error reading file:", err);
      return;
    }

    customer.Token = "HI";
    
    fs.writeFile("./db.json", JSON.stringify(customer), err => {
      if (err) console.log("Error writing file:", err);
    });
  });


var questions = ['Cual es tu nombre?' ,
                 'Cual es tu Token?'  ,
                 'Cual es tu numero de orden?'
                ]

var answers = [];

function question(i){
    process.stdout.write(questions[i]);
}

process.stdin.on('data', function(data){
    answers.push(data.toString().trim());

    if(answers.length < questions.length){
        question(answers.length);
    }else{
        process.exit();
    }
    
})

question(0);
```

**y en mi JSON:**

```
{"name":"Jabibi","order_count":103,"Token":"HI"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Although it's possible to get your script working with traditional callbacks, I think switching to promises and modern `async`/`await` syntax would be easier to read and follow.
- `readline` (built-in module for Node.js) can be used for getting input from user.
- You can use `fs/promises` instead of `fs` to take advantage of promises.
- It seems like you were trying to create a new customer object (using the user's input) and then write it as JSON to your file system.
- The script below writes to a temporary file path. Once tested that the right data is getting correctly written to a file, you can change the file path (I didn't want to overwrite an existing file on your machine).

---

```
const fs = require("fs/promises");

const readline = require("readline").createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

function getUserInput(displayText) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    readline.question(displayText, resolve);
  });
}

const questions = [
  ["name", "Cual es tu nombre?"],
  ["token", "Cual es tu Token?"],
  ["order_count", "Cual es tu numero de orden?"],
];

async function main() {
  const newCustomer = {};

  for (const [property, question] of questions) {
    const answer = await getUserInput(question.concat("\n"));
    newCustomer[property] = answer;
  }

  console.log("New customer:", newCustomer);

  const oldCustomer = await fs
    .readFile("./db.json")
    .then((data) => data.toString("utf-8"))
    .then(JSON.parse);

  // You can do something with old customer here, if you need to.
  console.log("Old customer:", oldCustomer);

  // I don't want to overwrite any existing file on your machine.
  // You can change the file path and data below to whatever they should be
  // once you've got your script working.
  await fs.writeFile(
    `./db_temp_${Date.now()}.json`,
    JSON.stringify(newCustomer)
  );

}

main()
  .catch(console.error)
  .finally(() => readline.close());
```

Comment: thanks a lot! it seems to work perfectly! I am going to study it to understand it well and continue applying it in my projects